# wants to pick most closest record in group of records in single table which input criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql

we have a table and there is possibility that one record can have multiple copies means same record can exist in table with multiple entries but their criteria will be different criteria is decided using three main parameters.income,score,no_months.these columns are integer.and we are grouping them by giving unique code to same records profile.
if one input is eligible for multiple profiles then we need to pick which is most matching to criteria.

**Sample Data.**

| id | name | income | score | no_months | group_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | abc | 1000 | 500 | 6 | abccode |
| 23 | abc | 900 | 600 | 12 | abccode |
| 24 | bca | 1000 | 600 | 12 | bcacode |

**Desired Results**

| id | name | income | score | no_months | group_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | abc | 900 | 600 | 12 | abccode |
| 24 | bca | 1000 | 600 | 12 | bcacode |

**Note: id 23 row has 2 columns which values are greater than id 22 row that is why id 23 was picked although id 23 has less income**

Only those records should be display which columns have more count of greater values than other row if group_code is same.

I have tried using multiple  order by with cte as more columns needs to display like image city etc. but its not working

Comment: what is the criteria to be used if there are 3 rows for id=23

Comment: And what column gets higher priority from income, score, no_months when there are multiple entries having the same name/group_code?

Comment: (1000, 600, 12) vs (900, 600, 15) ?

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph  id will be unique but it can have multiple replicas and income, score and no_months will be different. these are three fields which will be input to query.

Comment: @Agnij we need to decide on the based of three columns which row should we pick if group code is same if input criteria meets multiple replicas

Comment: @Serg if columns value greater count is equal then any column can be selected.
(1000, 600, 12) vs (900, 600, 15) here one columns is equal while one record has 1 greater value so greater count for both rows is one so any record can be selected

Comment: Have you tried rank() over(partition by groupcode,name order by income,score,no_months) as rank in cte and select rank=1

Comment: @saikumarvoruganti yes i have tried this but it overrides previous order by and filter it out only by last order by statement

Answer (score 0):

Select a single row for the `Name` or a winner of multiple rows. Winner is one with max score of wins when compared to others in a triangle join. Provided 2 rows has the same criteria, a row with the lesser id wins.

```
select * 
from tbl t
where id in (
     -- winners
     select winid
     from tbl t1 
     join tbl t2 on t1.name = t2.name and t1.id < t2.id
     join lateral (
        select case when sign(t1.income - t2.income) + sign(t1.score - t2.score) + sign(t1.no_months - t2.no_months) >= 0
                then t1.id else t2.id end winid
     ) w on 1=1
     group by winid
     order by count(*) desc
     limit 1) 
  or not exists(select 1 from tbl t3 where t3.name = t.name and t3.id <> t.id)
```